# Why does $a^x=e^{\ln(a^x)}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, exponentiation

Why does $a^x=e^{\ln(a^x)}$?

I know if I actually evaluate this I get
\begin{align}
\ln(a^x)&=\ln[e^{\ln(a^x)}] \\ x\ln(a)&=x\ln(a)
\underbrace{\ln(e)}_{1} \\ \therefore x\ln(a)&=x\ln(a)
\end{align}

But I want to know how I arrive to $a^x=e^{\ln(a^x)}$ without evaluating the equality.

Comment: You need to assume something here, or it's not true. If $a>0$ and $x\in\Bbb R$ then $a^x>0$, so this is just the definition of $\ln$; in fact $y=e^{\ln y}$ foor every $y>0$, has nnothing to do with the fact that here $t=a^x$.

Comment: It's simply $$e^{\ln(a^x)}=e^{x\ln(a)}=e^{\ln(a)x}=(e^{\ln (a)})^x=a^x$$ for $a>0$

Comment: @Fakemistake That can be its own answer as well. Why not post it as an answer?

Comment: @TobyMak It's done!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By definition, $\ln{a^x}$ equals a number that when $e$ is raised to that number, you get $a^x$. So, let's say that $\ln{a^x}=y$. Then, $e^y=a^x$. But we know what $y$ is in that last expression. It's equal to  $\ln{a^x}$. Thus, $e^{\ln{a^x}}=a^x$.

Answer (score 6):

The function $\ln:(0,\infty)\to\mathbb R$ is by definition the inverse of exponential function $\mathbb R\to(0,\infty)$.

So: $$y=e^{\ln(y)}\text{ for every }y\in(0,\infty)$$

Now substitute $y=a^x$.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how you define $\ln x$, one possible way is to define $f^{-1} (x) = \ln x$ as the inverse function of $f(x) = e^x$.

Then: $$e^{\ln(a^x)} =  f\Big(f^{-1} \left(a^x \right) \Big) = a^x$$.

Answer (score 1):

**Proof 1:** Show the equality from the right to the left. It's simply
$$\mathrm{e}^{\ln(a^x)}=\mathrm{e}^{x\ln(a)}=\mathrm{e}^{\ln(a)x}=(\mathrm{e}^{\ln(a)})^x=a^x$$
provided $a>0$ and $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

**Proof 2:** Let $a,b>0$ and $a\neq 1$ and consider $a^x=b$. Then you can define $x=\log_a(b)$, in case of $a=\mathrm{e}$ you can abbreviate $\ln(b)=\log_{\mathrm{e}}(b)$. In terms of $\ln(\cdot)$ the equation $a^x=b$ is rewritten $\mathrm{e}^{\ln(b)}=b$. Now just replace $b$ with $a^x$.